# why does SHGetFileInfo change the (current)culture?

Tags: vb.net, file, dropbox

Context: a program currently developed/maintained in VisualStudio2012, written in VB(.NET), targeting Framework v3.5. Most of our customers have a Dutch Windows installation and also most of them have their Regional Settings set to Dutch (nl-NL), implying the . (period) for grouping and the , (comma) as decimal separator.

Out of our almost 10,000 customers, only ONE (1) had a problem, the cause of which we identified as originating in a call to SHGetFileInfo to get a (small) icon for a file. Relevant statements in the code:

```
  Private Declare Unicode Function SHGetFileInfo Lib "Shell32.dll" Alias "SHGetFileInfoW" (pszPath As String, dwFileAttributes As UInteger, ByRef psfi As SHFILEINFO, cbSizeFileInfo As UInteger, uFlags As UInteger) As IntPtr
```

and

```
Dim result As IntPtr = SHGetFileInfo(pszPath, dwFileAttributes, psfi, cbSizeFileInfo, uFlags)
```

We assessed that - at the particular PC of this customer - before the (first) call to SHGetFileInfo the System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture was (nl-NL), as expected, but immediately after the call the CurrentCulture had switched to (en-US), which obviously caused problems elsewhere.

Pausing the code at that point and inspecting the Configuration Panel, the Regional Settings THERE were still Dutch (nl-NL). Also, no SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged (or -Changing) events were caught in the code. After stopping and restarting the program, the CurrentCulture in the program was again Dutch (nl-NL) - until the first SHGetFileInfo call.

In a practical sense we solved the issue by resetting the CurrentCulture if necessary:

```
  Private Declare Unicode Function SHGetFileInfo0 Lib "Shell32.dll" Alias "SHGetFileInfoW" (pszPath As String, dwFileAttributes As UInteger, ByRef psfi As SHFILEINFO, cbSizeFileInfo As UInteger, uFlags As UInteger) As IntPtr


  Private Shared Function SHGetFileInfo(pszPath As String, dwFileAttributes As UInteger, ByRef psfi As SHFILEINFO, cbSizeFileInfo As UInteger, uFlags As UInteger) As IntPtr

    Dim ciBefore As System.Globalization.CultureInfo = Application.CurrentCulture

    Dim result As IntPtr = SHGetFileInfo0(pszPath, dwFileAttributes, psfi, cbSizeFileInfo, uFlags)

    Dim ciAfter As System.Globalization.CultureInfo = Application.CurrentCulture
    If (ciAfter.Name <> ciAfter.Name) OrElse (ciBefore IsNot ciAfter) Then
      Application.CurrentCulture = ciBefore
    End If

    Return result
  End Function
```

Since the problem showed up only on that particular customer-PC, I had to analyze the issue on his PC , limiting my time to check things out. So, after solving the issue for him in the practical sense, I'm left with the unpleasant fact that I don't know how this could happen and my question, therefore, is: can anybody shed some light in this darkness?

Additional information: the customer did not have this problem until a month ago. Recently he has started using (and presumably installed) DropBox and BoxSync. I have no knowledge of the internal workings of these, but as they also "use files" and their installations more or less coincide with the problem showing up, I do have suspicions that there may be a connection.

I hope I've sufficiently stated the issue, but if more information is needed, I'll be glad to try and provide this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thread's CurrentCulture property is an unmanaged property under the hood.  Native code can call SetThreadLocale() to change it.  So it is not entirely mysterious why the culture changes when you pinvoke an unmanaged function.

Furthermore, shell functions like SHGetFileInfo() are subject to the behavior of shell extensions.  There are lots of them out in the wild and not infrequently causing problems like this.  Calling SetThreadLocale() is a convenient way to fix a formatting problem, not restoring the locale is a gross bug, particularly in a shell extension since it runs in the context of other processes.

Don't fix this problem by changing your code, tell the customer to fix his machine.  The best way to do so is by running the SysInternals' [AutoRuns utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx).  The Explorer tab shows a list of all installed shell extensions.  Disable everything that doesn't have "Microsoft" in the Publisher column.  Log-out + log-in to make it effective.  If he can't live without some of these extensions then he can re-enable them one by one to find the troublemaker.

Comment: Thanks Hans (again: as with my other question today), it's always a pleasure to learn. BTW: we do have (and intend to maintain) fixes that do not address errors in our own code, but "external" issues. Nevertheless, I'll inform the customer and - if he so desires - help him get rid of stuff that may also interfere with other programs he's using.